# I want to convert the following Object into a specific format mentioned below in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, logic, javascript-objects

I'm struggling to write the logic to convert the below Object into a specific format in Javascript. I might have to use recursions and other logic but I'm very new to Javascript and finding it difficult.

Object:

```
{
    "type": "GROUP",
    "match": {
        "text": "All",
        "value": "all"
    },
    "id": "cc155d32-eea8-4c5c-86d5-f5407ff55480",
    "childrens": [{
            "type": "GROUP",
            "match": {
                "text": "All",
                "value": "all"
            },
            "id": "954b2059-2f73-45bf-b88c-02ea4abc43f9",
            "childrens": [{
                    "type": "EXPRESSION",
                    "op": {
                        "text": "Contains",
                        "operator": "contains"
                    },
                    "field": {
                        "text": "TFN Description",
                        "value": "tfndesc",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "value": "abb",
                    "id": "1f40771c-ac67-4f98-97f1-0e8b998da7a5"
                },
                {
                    "type": "GROUP",
                    "match": {
                        "text": "All",
                        "value": "all"
                    },
                    "id": "c4038e59-1e84-4843-ac0e-cf4f51ab56dc",
                    "childrens": [{
                            "type": "EXPRESSION",
                            "op": {
                                "text": "Is equal to",
                                "operator": "eq"
                            },
                            "field": {
                                "text": "Call Center",
                                "value": "callcenter",
                                "type": "custom"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "lookupid": 620,
                                "lookupname": "Callcenter",
                                "lookupvalue": "Bloom",
                                "displaytext": "Bloom",
                                "text": "Bloom",
                                "value": "Bloom"
                            },
                            "id": "8f6ae19f-5821-4ee9-870e-817f1e95ad3b"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "EXPRESSION",
                            "op": {
                                "text": "Is equal to",
                                "operator": "eq"
                            },
                            "field": {
                                "text": "Is Retired",
                                "value": "isRetired",
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "text": "Yes",
                                "value": true
                            },
                            "id": "c1749714-bda1-489f-b32d-2d03387822be"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "EXPRESSION",
                    "op": {
                        "text": "Contains",
                        "operator": "contains"
                    },
                    "field": {
                        "text": "Req. Title",
                        "value": "title",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "value": "yyy",
                    "id": "f10f8d10-1261-4ca7-bac1-731fa4bca7ab"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "EXPRESSION",
            "op": {
                "text": "Is equal to",
                "operator": "eq"
            },
            "field": {
                "text": "DID",
                "value": "did",
                "type": "number"
            },
            "value": "46689988",
            "id": "ece14312-6e2f-4249-881b-e2db7bcdf3fe"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert the above structure into below format:

```
{
    "filter": [{
            "group": [{
                    "field": "tfndesc",
                    "criteria": [{
                        "op": "contains",
                        "value": "abb"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "op": "and"
                },
                {
                    "group": [{
                            "field": "callcenter",
                            "criteria": [{
                                "op": "is",
                                "value": "Bloom "
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            "op": "and"
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "isRetired",
                            "criteria": [{
                                "op": "is",
                                "value": true
                            }]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "field": "title",
                    "criteria": [{
                        "op": "contains",
                        "value": "yyy "
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "op": "and"
        },
        {
            "field": "did",
            "criteria": [{
                "op": "is",
                "value": "46689988"
            }]
        }
    ],
    "order": {
        "field": "title",
        "type": "desc"
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me write the logic/code for this in Javascript?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you be more specific about the way tthe 2 objects must be related.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like the first Object is meant to show the object type that you're provided with match being arguments. If you take a look at the second object it has keywords like "contain" and "group" and so on. I have no idea what exactly you're trying to do but this seems like an exercise to me, so that's what I'm assuming. There's collection operators that I think you're trying to get. It seems like the idea would be something like this:

```
group.filter(group => group.id === "954b2059-2f73-45bf-b88c-02ea4abc43f9").childrens.filter(child => child.field === "tfndesc") ...
```

and so on...

But to be frank, with the code provided, I am not really sure what exactly I am looking at. I think we're missing a lot of info.